# Any way to create multiple versions of classes within application?

Tags: c#, winforms

Okay so i'm newbie programmer creating a little game/application just for fun in c# in visual studio 2010 using windows forms. Its a "Youtube Tycoon" and i want the player to be able to create multiple videos  in the application and wondering whats the best way to go about this. I created a little console window version that just used several arrays but i wanted it to be more sophisticated.

So I have a class that has a few properties like a name and amount of views and weather its released or in production and I want the user to be able to create multiple versions of this.

Any pointers on the best way to achieve this?  As i said i'm quite new to this so simple informative answers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would be the differences between versions?

Comment: Have a property which indicates this information.  Are you really going to create a program that interacts with a video file at your skill level?

Comment: Oh the videos aren't real videos, they're just a name and some stats like views and such

Answer (score 0):

I ***think*** that you want to create multiple video objects when you say versions? As in:

```
var video1  = new YouTubeVideo("Some video title");
var video2  = new YouTubeVideo("Some other title");
```

That's how you do it. To keep track of all videos, you can keep them in collection classes like `List<T>`.

You can do it as:

```
var myVideos = new List<YouTubeVideo>();
myVideos.Add(new YouTubeVideo("Some video title"));
myVideos.Add(new YouTubeVideo("Some other title"));
```

The collection classes work just like arrays, but are a bit more flexible (as they can grow and shrink in size). They manage an array internally.

To remove a video you can just do:

```
myVideos.Remove(avideo);
```

and to fetch one:

```
var secondVideo = myVideos[1]; // <-- get the second video, as indexing starts with zero.
```

There are also something called LINQ which can be used to query collections:

```
var otherVideo = myVideos
                    .Where(video => video.Title.Contains("other")) // go through all videos and search for "other" in the title
                    .FirstOrDefault(); //return the first match or null
```

Comment: Don't worry i think i get this. just need some time to think about it

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can suggest in this case, since you are new to programming, is to read up on Object-Oriented programming. Here are some links to get you started:

[Object-Oriented Programming (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx)

[Object-Oriented Concepts in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tusharkantagarwal/objectorientedcsharp11162005070743AM/objectorientedcsharp.aspx)

Once you command an understand (if only basic to begin with) of object oriented programming, you should be able to solve this question yourself.

Comment: sorry i should probably say i'm not a complete noob... i get the basic ideas of object orientated programming inheritance and such. i was just looking at generic lists and stuff and came to a bit of a mind blank of how to do this